# Add score its not stop c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to add a some points to my score variable but its not stop to add points to it.
I have try to made a variable bool but its not solved the problem.
i don't know what i miss there.
This is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class certo2_3 : MonoBehaviour {
public static bool onoffrune;

void OnCollisionEnter()
{
    this.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ().enabled = false;
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled = false;

    //Debug.Log (ScoreSystem.frutos);
    //Invoke ("Respawn",5);
}

void Respawn()
{
    this.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ().enabled = true;
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled = true;
}

// use this for initialization
void Start () {
    this.GetComponent<BoxCollider> ().enabled = false;
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled = false;

}

// update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (triggerrune2_2.certo22 == 1) 
    {
        Respawn();
        scoreplus();
    }

}
public void scoreplus()
{
    onoffrune = true;
    if (onoffrune = true) {
        scoreManager.score += 10;
    }
    onoffrune = false;
}
}
```

Comment: To test equality use two `==` signs. But its pointless because you set your variable to true on the line before checking whether its `true`

Comment: You need to explain your issue better. It is not clear what the problem is

Comment: @musefan well i try to add some points to my score but wen i call function its not stop anymore to add points to the variable

Comment: I guess what you mean is you only want the score to update once (on collision) bu it updates every frame. To fix that you need to address the logic of testing `triggerrune2_2.certo22 == 1`. You need to find a way for that to get reset after the score had been applied so the logic is not true again on the next frame

Comment: @ines still not clear. Obviously English is not your first language but `its not stop anymore to add points` does ntot make a whole lot of sense. What is the pooint of the variable `onoffrune`

Comment: @musefan tank you for the help its true English its not my first lang its what you say i want my score update only once but its keep to add continuous

Comment: @Jamiec: I can only assume he means he wants to add only 10 points once, but after it starts it keeps adding 10 points every frame and doesn't stop

Comment: @musefan yes, well decoded :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you have provided is very limited, so I can only show you a solution that will fix the problem. I cannot ensure that my solution is the best for your overall design, hopefully it will be enough to show you what the problem is and how to address it:

```
void Update () 
{
    if (triggerrune2_2.certo22 == 1) 
    {
        Respawn();
        scoreplus();
        triggerrune2_2.certo22 = 0; // Reset this so it isn't true for subsequent frames.
    }
}

public void scoreplus()
{
    scoreManager.score += 10;
}
```

Notice that I have reset `triggerrune2_2.certo22` to `0` so the if statement doesn't succeed on subsequent evaluations. Of course, I have no idea what `triggerrune2_2.certo22` is to say if `0` is the correct value. Hopefully you will see the logic and decide what value is appropriate for your design.

Again I want to stress, this is only one possible solution of many. But it is all I can offer based on the limited code you have provided.

---

If you are wanting to use `onoffrune` as a method to determine if score should be applied you can do this:

```
public onoffrune = false;

void Update () 
{
    if (triggerrune2_2.certo22 == 1 && onoffrune) 
    {
        Respawn();
        scoreplus();
        onoffrune = false;
    }
}

public void scoreplus()
{
    scoreManager.score += 10;
}
```

Note that you probably want `onoffrune` to be an instance variable, and not static, otherwise it will apply to all instances of MonoBehaviour and not each individual one (or maybe that is what you want I don't know)

Comment: But in fact onoffrune its a kind of a switch

Comment: @ines: I have made an update that uses `onoffrune`, maybe it will be of some use